# Singleton on clustered servers

Tags: java, design-patterns, websphere

I have an application which compares a complex set of rules against a transaction.  Because the rules don't change very often and there are lots of transactions, I made getting the rules from the database as a singelton (RuleInfo).  When a rule is changed, I call updateRuleInfo.

```
 public static void updateRuleInfo(){
      instance = new RuleInfo();
```

This worked great in my dev and test environments because they are both on single servers, however, our production environment is a WebSphere clustered environment (2 servers with 2 nodes each). As a result if the rules for a person or tool are updated, the change shows up on one node, but the user might try to make a transaction on another node and get the old set of rules.  I tried calling updateRuleInfo each time someone logs into the application, but that doesn't work all the time either.

Is there some way to update the singleton across all the nodes?

Comment: When the system starts up / restarts, where do you get the initial rule set from? Is it stored in a database?

Comment: When the system starts up, it gets the rules from the database.  Restarting the system, properly populates all the rules in all the nodes.  Of course, that is not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood you're using your singleton as data cache. So when the original data changes you must tell all singletons to invalidate their data so that they reload themselves the next time they are accessed.

One way to accomplish this is using the JMS publish/subscriber pattern. Deploy a JMS topic; all singleton services subscribe to that topic and get notified whenever their datasource changes.

See http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue052.html (Chapter 'Distributed Singleton Caches').

Answer (score 0):

Singletons in an clustered environment are tricky

Check this solutions :

**[Singleton Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/cluster/service_migration.html#wp1051458)**

**[Hazelcast with a distributed lock](http://www.hazelcast.com/)**

[Memcache](http://memcached.org/) ( if the amount of data fits into memory )

Best is to run the singleton on every node and get the data from a unique backend

Regards

Comment: The singelton is in the code on all the nodes, the question is how to call an UPDATE that gets sent to all the nodes.

Comment: Try Hazelcast use a Map/List as a cache. All nodes will have some parts of your data . update, insert and delete operations are always propagated. If you access the cache you will get all items